# Merge several Guava multisets into one

Tags: java, collections, guava, multiset

I would like to create an immutable view on the sum of a number (>2) of immutable Guava multisets. The multisets are in a list. I don't want to copy the contents into a new multiset. I could probably use `Multisets.sum(Multiset, Multiset)` and reduce my stream of Multisets with it, but it seems a bit wasteful to create a summed multiset for every intermediate step. Is there a better way?

In other words: I want a method similar to `Multisets.sum(Multiset, Multiset)`, but then for a list of multisets instead of just two. The signature could be: `<T> Multiset<T> sum(List<Multiset<T>>)`.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @notionquest I have a `List<Multiset<T>>` and I want an immutable `Multiset<T>` backed by these multisets, where they are combined in the same way as `Multisets.sum(Multiset, Multiset)`. It's not really an example, hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: You might consider creating an issue at https://github.com/google/guava/issues to suggest adding `Multisets.sum(Multiset...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `Multisets.sum(Multiset, Multiset)` is implemented in the way it doesn't copy contents but rather creates a view over two multisets, so in your case looping over list of multisets and copying only final result to a new immutable multiset is fine (overhead from views should not matter for *small number of multisets*). Using Java 8 you can combine Multiset's `sum` with [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
public <T> Multiset<T> sum(final List<Multiset<T>> multisets)
{
    return multisets.stream().reduce(ImmutableMultiset.of(), Multisets::sum);
}
```

**EDIT**

However although there'll be no copying involved in approach above, as @LouisWasserman noted most optimal solution (YMMV) could be just accumulate results in new multiset:

```
public <T> ImmutableMultiset<T> sum(final List<Multiset<T>> multisets)
{
    final ImmutableMultiset.Builder<T> builder = ImmutableMultiset.builder();
    multisets.forEach(builder::addAll);
    return builder.build();
}
```

Having dedicated view class (see @OliverGregoire's answer) is also an option if needed.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that create a lot of intermediate multisets during reduction? The final multiset would basically be big tree of all these multisets. This seems wasteful. What do you think?

Comment: Creating a view class is cheap and for input list of size <100 (I made up that number) it should not matter and would be a premature optimization IMO. *If* you want to optimize here, do benchmarks and profile your code first. Having smaller codebase and re-using library goodies is bigger gain for me than creating yet-another-class (which you have to maintain) for very narrow task.

Comment: Thanks. Reasonable points. Actually I had already implemented it in a similar way as you suggest, but I was still curious if there's a better solution.

Comment: @Rinke, there are only two options: creating a view, or accumulating into a new multiset.  There really aren't any other choices.  Creating a view, which this approach will do, I'd expect to create a significant performance overhead: each call to any operation in the multiset is going to recurse through every multiset that was put in, and I'd expect some operations to possibly get quadratic in the number of multisets being combined.  I would advise going ahead and accumulating into a new multiset, not a new multiset for each pair but just adding everything into one big multiset.

Answer (score 4):

There are no methods that do that out of the box.

However, remember that Guava is licensed under Apache License so you can look and reuse the code (as long as you respect the license requirements).

The source is available [here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.java#L556).

With that in mind, you can create your own class, similar in structure to Guava's `Multisets.sum(Multiset,Multiset)`:

```
public class SummedMultiset<T> extends AbstractMultiset<T> {
  private final ImmutableList<Multiset<T>> multisets;
  public SummedMultiset(List<Multiset<T>> multisets) {
    this.multisets = ImmutableList.copyOf(multisets);
  }
  @Override public int count(Object element) {
    return multisets.stream().mapToInt(m -> m.count(element)).sum();
  }
  // Fill all the other methods seen in Guava's source.
}
```

Of course, you can hide that implementation behind a method:

```
public class MoreMultisets {
  public static Multiset<T> sum(List<Multiset<T>> multisets) {
    return new SummedMultiset<>(multisets);
  }
}
```